Enabling/disabling SQL Server foreign keys in DBeaver
How to enable/disable foreign keys with DBeaver on SQL Server. I mean in IDE how to produce:
ALTER TABLE mytable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_mytable


Not all IDEs support all kind of manipulations, so it might be that what you're looking for isn't possible in DBeaver
